# Vertices of $G$ covered entirely by disjoint $k$-stars

Tags: graph-theory, matching-theory

Let $k \in \mathbb{N}$ with $k \geq 2$, and consider a bipartite graph with vertex classes $A,B$ such that $\mid B \mid = k\mid A \mid$. Using Hall's theorem on a suitable graph $G'$, show that if $ \mid N(S)\mid \geq k\mid S \mid$ for all $S \subseteq A$ then the vertices of $G$ can be covered entirely by disjoint $k$-stars (a $k$-star is a tree with $k+1$ vertices and $k$ leaves)

Comment: my rough thoughts. We start of with $G$, and then select a subgraph $G'$ where $\mid A \mid $ = $ \mid B' \mid$, and we then consider this new subgraph. Clearly here, since we have a bi-partite graph, we can apply halls theorem to it as $\mid N(S) \mid \geq \mid S \mid$. So we've found a matching. Then we consider $G'' =  G - B'$, and then find a subgraph of $G''$ s.t $\mid A \mid = \mid B'' \mid$, and then continue this way. We would continue this $k$ times. After this, each $a \in A$ would have degree $k$ and all of $G$ would be covered, so $G$ can be covered entirely by disjoint $k$-stars.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the bipartite graph $G'$ with vertex classes $A$ and $C=\{U\subset B:|U|=k\}$. A vertex $a\in A$ is connected in $G'$ to a vertex $c\in C$ iff $a$ is connected to all $b \in c$ in $G$. Now, since for every $\varnothing\neq S\subseteq A$, $|N_G(S)|\geq k|S|$, then $|N_{G'}(S)|\geq{k|S| \choose k}\geq|S|$. Therefore, there is a matching in $G'$ that covers $A$. Construct a $k$-star covering by connecting each element of $A$ in $G$ to all the elements of the subset that matched that element in $G'$.

Comment: Sorry, i'm a little confused at the first line, did you mean to say $C= \{ U \subset B : \mid U \mid = k \}$?

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. I fixed the typo.